# Redis mark key volatile infinite expiration

Tags: redis

I want to mark keys as volatile but I dont want redis to expire them unless I hit a max memory configuration.

Is it possible to mark a key as volatile but do so with an infinite value?

**edit**

I searched the googles and the mailing list and am not finding anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in your case, there is no need to do the normal key expiration, you could try this trick method. **But if you also want to expire some keys in normal ways, then the method is wrong.**

Set the Memory-policy to **volatile-ttl** which can

> evict keys with an expire set, and try to evict keys with a shorter time to live (TTL) first, in order to make space for the new data added.

And use expire command on that volatile keys.

```
expire volatile-key infinite-time
```

The infinite-time should be very big to make sure that key will not be expired in the normal way.

Then if your redis server reaches the maxmemory, it will follow the volatile-ttl policy and remove the oldest volatile-key you define first.

Comment: Thanks, I just set the value really high as you suggested.